# Rails relationship's advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, entity-relationship

I need to model the following relationships and would like some advice on how to properly model it.

There is a user, house, apartment, garden, furniture

1. So a user can either have a house or an apartment but not both.
2. Both house and apartment can have furniture but only the house can have garden.

So the biggest issue is user has_one house | has_one apartment, how can I model this ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using single table inheritance for this (a little wasteful because of all the null gardens, but depending on the scale of your db, that may not end up being an issue), or possibly a polymorphic relationship (user has_one dwelling).

Comment: Can you explain the user has_one dwelling ? I'd be nice if you can say if this is the polymorphic association, and then how will for instance house and apartment would look like. I made a quick sketch and it was  belongs_to :user, :as=>dwelling. I am not sure if this will work though.

Comment: check out the docs at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html for an example that should translate well to your example. Also, railscasts are always a good starting point: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association  -- it's important to practice taking the docs and translating them into your scenario, so that you really understand what's going on (and can maintain the code)

Comment: (the user has_one dwelling comment was just what was in my mind -- I haven't sketched it out, so you may be right that it should be a belongs_to relationship instead)